# How to use verified certificate to set telegram bot Webhook?

Tags: ssl, nginx, bots, telegram

I have verified ssl certificate (got it when bought hosting). It consist of four parts: 1. private key, 2. certificate, 3. root sertificate, 4.  intermediate certificate. I made two files .key(private), .crt(certificate, intermediate, root) and confugure nginx. Everything good, my domain shows https, and https://www.sslshopper.com says that it works.
But when I set telegram bot webhook

```
def start_request():
    url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/{method}'.format(
        token = 'myToken',
        method = 'setWebhook'
    )
    data = {
        'url' : 'MyDomain',
        'certificate' : open('myCertificate', 'r')
    }
    r = requests.post(url, data = data)
```

webhook status always

result
url "myDomain"
has_custom_certificate  false
pending_update_count    5
last_error_date 1515041749
last_error_message  "Wrong response from the webhook: 403 Forbidden"

and 
nginx log says 
149.154.167.214 - - [04/Jan/2018:07:07:00 +0300] "POST myDomain" 403 997 "-" "-"

Is certificate problem ?
What certificate or part of the certificate and in what format I should send to telegram ?

Comment: Can you try curl yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `setWebhook` is seccessd. You can use [this Android application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=taipei.sean.telegram.botplayground) to determine.

[image: Awesome Telegram Bot]

BTW, you can refer to [this guide](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks#testing-your-bot-with-updates), use `curl` to debug yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I take root certificate (only root) and convert it to .der and to .pem ,

```
openssl x509 -in root.crt -outform der -out root.der
openssl x509 -in root.der -inform der -outform pem -out root.pem
```

after that I set webhook with "Awesome Telegram Bot" android application using root.pem certificate.
And using getWebhookInfo method I get

```
url "https://myDomain"
has_custom_certificate  true
```